# ext:Button not showing up, even though rendered=true

Tags: button, ext.net

so I got some quite simple markup containing a button inside a Toolbar.

The problem now is, even though the button is "correctly" written to DOM it does not show up.
See this screenshot for details:

[image: screenshot]

would someone mind explaining why setting fixed heights / widths / positions does not bring the button to front and the containing markup elements all have either `width=0px;` or `height=0px;`?

Here comes a sample:

```
<body>
<ext:ResourceManager ID="RM" runat="server" />
<ext:Viewport Layout="BorderLayout" runat="server" ID="InnerView" OverflowY="Scroll">
    <Content>
        <ext:Button ID="adminswap" runat="server" Text="Admin-Ansicht umschalten" Hidden="false"
            AllowDepress="true" MinHeight="16" ToFrontOnShow="true" Visible="true" Icon="ArrowSwitchBluegreen">
            <%-- This Guy doesn't show up--%>
        </ext:Button>
        <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="order" Border="false" OverflowY="Scroll">
            <LayoutConfig> 
                <ext:TableLayoutConfig Columns="3" />
            </LayoutConfig>
            <Items>
                <ext:Panel runat="server" Layout="ColumnLayout" RowSpan="2" Border="false">
                    <Content>
                       <p> And here is some Grid-panel, which is of no further interest</p>
                    </Content>
                </ext:Panel>
                <ext:Panel ColSpan="2" runat="server" ID="Panel_Instructions" Title="Türöffnung per Telefon"
                    Width="740" Padding="10" Border="true" AutoHeight="true">
                    <Content>
                        <br />
                        <p>
                            Some Multiline text containing instructions<br>
                            this also is of no further interest and just for the sake of the sample<br><br> lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet and stuff...
                        </p>
                    </Content>
                </ext:Panel>
                <ext:Panel runat="server" Width="350" AutoHeight="false" Height="200"
                    StripeRows="true" TrackMouseOver="true" Border="true">
                    <Content>
                       <p>Some Content Grid-Panel</p>
                    </Content>
                </ext:Panel>
                <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="Standort_Details" Title="Adresse" Width="370" Padding="10"
                    AutoHeight="false" Height="200" Border="true">
                    <Items>
                        <ext:DisplayField ID="Details_field1" runat="server" FieldLabel="street"
                            Name="" />
                        <ext:DisplayField ID="Details_field2" runat="server" FieldLabel="postal code" Name="" />
                        <ext:DisplayField ID="Details_field3" runat="server" FieldLabel="city" Name="" />
                        <ext:DisplayField ID="Details_field4" runat="server" FieldLabel="phone" Name="" />
                    </Items>
                </ext:Panel>
                <ext:Panel ID="Panel_5" Border="true" Height="460" StyleSpec="vertical-align:top;" ColSpan="3" runat="server">
                    <Content>
                        <p> some content control grid-panel</p>
                    </Content>
                </ext:Panel>
            </Items>
        </ext:Panel>
      </Content>
  </ext:Viewport>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide sample to reproduce?

Comment: Your sample is not runnable. It requires some changes to get it runnable. Though even doing those changes it doesn't reproduce the problem for me. I see the button.

The single thing here I can suggest is replacing <Content> with <Items>.

Comment: @DaniilVeriga i tried make it runnable now, so i just C&P + anonymised the code in the body also replaced content with items, but no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A BorderLayout works with regions. You don't specify any regions. To get the Button visible you can just remove the Layout="BorderLayout" of the Viewport.

Here is [an example of using a BorderLayout](http://examples.ext.net/#/Layout/BorderLayout/Simple_in_Markup/).